# Newbie to Ubuntu - Need a little Setup help (15.10 won't shut down)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, shutdown, gparted

So I decided to turn my Laptop from Windwos 8.1 into a dualboot with Ubuntu and thus installed Ubuntu 15.10 through a memory stick. My goal was that I could choose between the OS I want everytime I start up.

After some initial expenditure I seemed to get the OS working fairly well, and thanks to GRUB I can choose the OS I want every time I boot.

However, the one huge issue I could not fix is Ubuntu simply wont shut down. Instead the screen just freezes, so I have to force shutdown everytime by pressing the button.

When starting up, I get an error named "Secure Boot Violation" Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup.

After pressing ok the Laptop boots normally however.

I tried so far:
changing
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
into
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"` 
--> Did not work.

I reinstalled Grub through Bootrepair and let it run through. 
( /paste.ubuntu.com/15473378 )

--> Did not work either

Furthermore, I cannot reboot, I cannot sign out, I cannot log off, and I cannot shutdown by commandline (tried `sudo -shutdown -h now`) it all results into freezing

Now before I mess up too much I wanted to ask you guys for help.

I am using a MSI MS-16H2 Notebook

---

Where I suspect the error might be situated in:

Gparted does always give me an error message when I run it, first:

"The Argument is invalid, while /dev/sda was positioned for reading."

When I click ignore, I get another error called:

"The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used."

--> After clicking ok. I can use Gparted normally.

After I ran boot-repair, I was told that I should make sure that the boot-partition is located in /dev/sdc

--> Now here I think where the error is.

Because I find a BOOT-Partition (fat32, /boot/efi) in:

/dev/mapper/isw/dddegaaaac_RAID0IMSVolume2

And then I find the BIOS_RVY Partition in /dev/sdc

(where I was told the boot-partition must be)

Do you guys think this might be the error? And if not, what else might I have to consider so that my Notebook will finally shut down? Furthermore, if I change the Location of the Boot-Partition now, could this harm the Windows-OS?

--> If someone could tell me how I can rename this Raid's horrible name I'd be quite happy too.

Also, there are 2 Disks à 119 GB (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb) which are labelled "not assigned" --> I think this is where the initial error message in Gparted comes from. Can I use them or may I not change them because they contain some curcial windows-data or something?

I posted the Images of Gparted and the Link after boot-repair to make it more clear.

Thanks alot for dealing with my issues.

[Gparted 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmdRy.jpg)

[Gparted 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv5Zo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried those steps in order to remove the "Secure Boot Violation" error ?

> 1) Restart your computer
>
> 2) Bring up the BIOS configuration
>
> 3) Go to Security
>
> 4) Select Secure Boot configuration
>
> 5) Switch Secure Boot from enabled to disabled

Comment: I did change the Secure boot configuration now and the initial violation errer does no longer appear. Thank you. Unfortunately there's still no way to shut the computer down.. trying to downgrade my kernel now.